# iPhone - Create an images grid list

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I'm developing an application that get images from a website and display to user with a grid view like Photo app by Apple.

When you tap on an image I would to push a view controller that displays images info and other stuff.

What's the better way to implement this? I thought a custom UITableViewCell. (I've seen there are Three20 and AQGridView libs but I'm a newbie developer and the docs are very very poor. Hints?)

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the UITableView is the best way of doing it. Its memory efficient and your only going to display 3 images anyway so the overhead isn't that bad. A tip, when your asynchronously getting images from the website, create a custom view is a delegate of NSURLRequest, get the data from a webpage, parse the data into a UIImage using imageWithData and when the finished delegate method is called, put a imageview on top of the custom view. This is the best method of downloading asynchronous methods. Good luck!

Comment: Hey thank you for the reply! Can you show me some code to do this (or if you've a little tutorial)? Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

I made a thumbnail grid list like tableView but multicolumn, it's open source, on 
http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/thumbnail-list-view

https://github.com/mohammedDehairy/ThumbnailList