# How to display a large list of images using objective-c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Is there any tool to display images as a list and when selecting it the app should show the full size image? Can I use the custom cell for UITableView? Or is there any other alternative? I have searched UICollectionView but the tutorials are not much good. Can anyone help me?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: yes i will help you cos i created an app like this ....i show all the images on table view by list and detail about images ....on click event i show complete details corosponding image....if you want to show those all images show on full view thats also i o

Comment: what is the problem with collectionview? It's the best way to display list of Images

Comment: @priya Do you want images list like this? Check this link: http://ge.tt/7bBitS41/v/0?c

Answer (score 0):

I think the `UITableView` is the best way of doing it. Its memory efficient and your only going to display 3 images anyway so the overhead isn't that bad. A tip, when your asynchronously getting images from the website, create a custom view is a delegate of `NSURLRequest`, get the data from a webpage, parse the data into a `UIImage` using `imageWithData` and when the finished delegate method is called, put a imageview on top of the custom view. This is the best method of downloading asynchronous methods. Good luck!

This source have some example Links

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031879/iphone-create-an-images-grid-list)

Comment: its not 3 images. it may have large number of images. so as per the reply i should get the images using URL right?

Comment: @priya  yes! you get.

Answer (score 0):

You can use collection view but that will have a limitation that, Collection view is not supported by iOS 5 and earlier.

There are two ways:

1) Either you create you own logical grid with `UIBotton` with  setting each button `Tag` and encountering that button action and showing a large image which will show image with `UIImageView` you just need to set image to `UIImageView` and set `[imageView setHidden:NO]` on button click and put a button to hide the same..

2) Else the simpler way is to follow the [link](https://github.com/gdavis/FGallery-iPhone) the sample code for the images.

Enjoy...

Answer (score 0):

You can use UITableView to show large no. of images.

When you select an image and to show show full size image instead of thumbnail, You can use a custom popup view to show that image.

With pop up view you can also zoom in and zoom out that image by implementing tap Gesture recognizer on ImageView OR If you are using UIButton then you can implement its "UIControlEventTouchUpInside" event by adding a target.